# What is the use of equal sign two times in a statement

Tags: c

In the C language, what is the use of the equal sign twice in a statement? For example, in the following code statement — `*arr += *(arr + n - 1) += 10;` — there are two equal signs.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define SIZE(arr) sizeof(arr) / sizeof(*arr);

void fun(int* arr, int n)
{
    int i;
    *arr += *(arr + n - 1) += 10;
}

void printArr(int* arr, int n)
{
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        printf("%d ", arr[i]);
}

int main()
{
    int arr[] = {10, 20, 30};
    int size = SIZE(arr);
    fun(arr, size);
    printArr(arr, size);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Two different addition operations are being performed?

Comment: If you're programming in C then only add the C language tag.

Comment: Ouch.  You guys should really give a duplicate if you think it's such a bad question.  I don't think I've ever seen this construct in Java, and, to be honest, I don't have an explanation.

Comment: You should read chapter two of K&R C book

Comment: Have you searched about what `+=` operator does ?

Comment: Sadistic teachers think you need to understand it (they might be right).  Rigorous reviewers would reject code written like that as being abominably obscure and would send anyone who submitted it running to fix it.  You have an unwanted `;` in your `#define`.  It happens not to break your program, but only by fluke.  Your 'double assignment' should be using array subscript notation because it is clearer: `arr[0] += arr[n-1] += 10;` — but it is still appalling code that should be written `arr[n-1] += 10; arr[0] += arr[n-1];`.

Comment: thnx lot    ,, i got my mistake

Comment: I would send anyone who submitted it running to the Jobcentre, or sentence them to maintain their own code for a year:)

Comment: @MartinJames *sentence them to maintain their own code for a year*  Oh heck no. Because then someone else is going to have to spend three years cleaning up the mess. If you're forced to keep such a coder on your team, give him a newspaper and hope he spends his day reading it. And I'm serious - that kind of code is such a mess and makes so much more work for others it's literally better to have such a poor developer doing **nothing**.  And yeah, I've done that. My boss (also a good friend) tells me "You have to give him work."  "No, I don't."

Comment: @AndrewHenle LOL, yes.  I've tried so many times to emphasize that, for most projects, ease of testing and debugging is more important than performance, because they are the phases where the money disappears - into continual test/debug/fix.  Writing code is easy, getting the data right is hard, delivering working apps is very hard indeed...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means, add 10 to `arr[n-1]`, then add the new `arr[n-1]` value to `arr[0]`.

Comment: To extend on this: assignment operators also return the value of what they assigned.

For a simpler example, a=b=5 is like a=(b=5), 5 gets stored in b, and the result of that (5) gets put in a.